# why method in lambda expression is executed

Tags: c#, lambda, ienumerable

I have a simple test program and wonder why the console 
output is 1 instead of 6?
Thank you.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var t = new List<int>() {1, 1, 1, 1, 1};
        var s = new List<int>() {1};

        var g = t.Select(a => test(a, s));
            Console.WriteLine(s[0]);    
    }

    private static int test(int a, List<int> s )
    {
        s[0]++;
        return a;
    }
```

Comment: Because of deferred execution. Add `.ToList()` to the end of that `Select` line.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[IEnumerable is lazy](http://brianreiter.org/2011/01/14/ienumerable-is-lazy-and-thats-cool/). The expression is not evaluated until it is needed, so `test` is never called.

Add `Console.WriteLine(g.ToList());` and you will see how the `test` method is now called. You can force it to be evaluated in your code by using: `var g = t.Select(a => test(a, s)).ToList();` This will cause the enumerable to be evaluated into a list.

See [Lazy Evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation):

> In programming language theory, lazy evaluation, or call-by-need is an evaluation strategy which delays the evaluation of an expression until its value is needed (non-strict evaluation) and which also avoids repeated evaluations (sharing).

Note: It is generally discouraged to use LINQ code that causes side effects, see the 4th paragraph of [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx).